# What were some 19th century objections to the existence of absolute zero?

Tags: physics, 19th-century

William Thomson (Lord Kelvin) proposed the existence of an absolute zero in 1848(1) by linearly extrapolating the experimentally determined volume-temperature law for gases. I recently learned that some scientists in 19th century objected to the existence of absolute zero but I have been unable to find such criticisms (2).

(1) On an Absolute Thermometric Scale
https://zapatopi.net/kelvin/papers/on_an_absolute_thermometric_scale.html

(2) The youtuber in this video clip states that those who called themselves 'energetics' did not believe in entropy or the absolute zero scale for temperature:
https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxT8US1xpLy0h_x3wJqdgK-bRzP4eMLrFN

The complete video is here:
Boltzmann's Entropy Equation: A History from Clausius to Planck
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr_gv5CKB1Y